# PyMongo error: cannot convert value of type to bson

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using flask with pymongo, and i have the error:

> bson.errors.InvalidDocument
>
> InvalidDocument: cannot convert value of type  to bso

My code for this error is:

```
    def get_question_with_id(id,question):
         question = db.questions.find_one({'id': id})
         return question,id
```

I searched for many hours  for one solution, but i did not find answer for this problem.
what is this error?

Comment: Did you find answer to this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

def get_question_with_id(id,question):
         question = db.questions.find_one({'_id':ObjectId(id)})
         return question,id
```